# Aperture and networked drive: thinks images are offline

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, network-shares, aperture

I keep my photos on a networked drive (wireless), and they are referenced by Aperture.  Aperture seems to not try very hard to look for this drive.  Usually I have to open the network drive in Finder before opening Aperture -- otherwise it doesn't find the images and considers them offline.

To me this seems like Aperture isn't willing to look on the network for the drive, unless it was helped along by pointing it out in Finder.  It doesn't work if I start Aperture first and *then* navigate to the drive in Finder.

What are some workarounds to making this functional?  **Is there a way to tell Aperture to look again without restarting the program?**

**Edit:** No, it's not a disk image.  It's attached to a time capsule and accessible from finder under Shared > TimeCapsule > AttachedDrive

Comment: sounds more like an OSX mount problem than a problem with aperture.  maybe you need to make the mounts explicit so the shares are available?  hopefully an OSX expert can confirm/deny this suspicion and point you in the right direction.

Comment: is it a disk image on the network drive? That might be the issue.. not sure, I use Aperture locally.